# How to run appcenter command through Jenkins

Tags: xamarin, jenkins, xamarin.uitest, visual-studio-app-center, visual-studio-app-center-test

In order to execute Xamarin Test Cloud tests, you have to execute an appcenter command e.g.

```
appcenter test run uitest --app "appName" --devices 228faeda --app-path *appPath*  --test-series "master" --locale "en_US" --build-dir *debugFolderPath*
```

This works perfectly.

I want to trigger this command via Jenkins.

- I added "Execute Windows batch Command" with the command shown above.
- I execute the build.

But I get the following error in the Console Output

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Xamarin Test Cloud Android>appcenter
'appcenter' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

Why is that?

Thanks

Comment: you need to specify the full path to the appcenter exe, or otherwise set an environment variable with the path

Answer (score 9):

Make sure to install the appcenter-cli first.

```
npm install -g appcenter-cli@1.2.2
```

### Bash Script for App Center Test

Below is the bash script I use for my CI. To implement it, you'll first need to get an authentication token from App Center.

#### Manually Retrieve an API Token

The [App Center CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/appcenter/cli/?WT.mc_id=none-stackoverflow-bramin) requires the user to be logged in, and we can log in from our build server by providing a login token.

Using the App Center CLI, enter the following command, replacing `[Name Of Token]` with whatever you want to name this token

```
appcenter login
appcenter tokens create -d "[Name Of Token]"
```

It will provide a response like this:

> ID:          [Unique Guid]
>
> API Token:   [Unique API Token]
>
> Description: [Name of Token]
>
> Created at:  [Time Stamp]

#### App Center Test CI Script

The bash script does the following:

1. Locate the UI Test Build Directory

   - Replace `[My UI Test Assembly Name]` with the name of your UI Test assembly
2. Locate the APK file
3. Install the appcenter cli
4. Log in to App Center using the API Token

   - Replace `[login token]` with the value of your login token
   - Replace `[Your App Center App Name]` with the value of your app name
   - Replace `[Your Device Id]` with the value of your device id

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

UITestDLL=`find . -name "[My UI Test Assembly Name].dll" | grep bin`
UITestBuildDir=`dirname $UITestDLL`

APKFile=`find . -name *.apk | head -1`

npm install -g appcenter-cli@1.2.2

appcenter login --token [login token]

appcenter test run uitest --app "[Your App Center App Name]" --devices [Your Device Id] --app-path $APKFile --test-series "master" --locale "en_US" --build-dir $UITestBuildDir --async
```